# Java: number of times that the max value occurs in the array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

this code only display maximum occurred value not greatest value with maximum occurred.

```
System.out.println(countMax(new int[] {6,3,1,3,4,3,6,5}));

static int countMax(int[]a) {
    int count = 1, tempCount;
    int maxCount = a[0];
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {

        temp = a[i];
        tempCount = 0;

        for(int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {

            if(temp == a[j])
                tempCount++;
        }

        if(tempCount > count)

            maxCount = temp;
        count = tempCount;
    }

    return maxCount;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample test cases(examples) to support your question.

Comment: @Deepen SO is not intended to alter your code to new specifications, rather to provide guidance where you fail to implement it yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP hasn't tried to implement the new requirement himself

Comment: For example, countMax would return 2 if the array is {6. 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5} because 6 occurs 2 times in the array.

Comment: @Deepen so basically you want to count how many times the maximum number of the array occur in the array.

Comment: To count the number of times the highest value occurs, don't you think you need to figure out what the highest value is? I see no attempt at that, so: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: yes, like here in example {6. 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5} 3 occurred 3 times and 6 occurred 2 times- output is 2 because 6 is greater value then 3.

Comment: The code does not display anything at all. Is it meant to, or should it return both the max value and the count?

Comment: To find out, how often the maximum value occurs in your array, first, *find* the maximum value, second, *count* it. Should be easy if done in two steps.

Comment: @isnot2bad Can be done in a single iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should approach a two-step solution:

1. Find the maximum value in the array
2. Count, how often this maximum value occurs

Therefore, you have to iterate the array twice - once to find the maximum value and once to count it.

If you have still problems, here is the code snippet:

```
public static int countMax(int[] values) {
    // first, find the maximum value
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, values[i]);
    }

    // then count the maximum value
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        if (values[i] == maxValue) maxCount++;
    }

    return maxCount;
}
```

Comment: @isnot2bad See first part of [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50922064/5221149), which does it in one iteration, faster and with no extra memory consumption.

Comment: @Javafan-Shashank- You're right! I'll take my comment back! I'll still leave my answer as an alternative approach.

Answer (score 4):

You have to keep an additional variable with the count of the current maximal value as you go. You don't need two loops for this, only one:

```
static int countMax(int[] a) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int count = 0;
    for (int curr : a) {
        if (curr > max) {
            max = curr;
            count = 1;
        } else if (curr == max) {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Alternatively, Java 8's streams provide a pretty easy, albeit not too performant way of doing all the heavy lifting for you:

```
static int countMax(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                 .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                 .orElse(0L)
                 .intValue();
}
```

Comment: *"Java 8's streams provide a pretty easy [...] way"*? Really? You think that is an easy way? It takes about the same amount of code to write, is more obscure, and performs badly by comparison.

Comment: @Javafan-Shashank- The first one works because the 'current biggest' value will be temporarily stored. If it occures more often a counter gets increased. If there is a bigger value available the counter gets reset to 1 and the whole process starts over again for the rest of the array. It's bulletproof.

Comment: @L.Spillner yes first i misunderstood it, but as soon i realized it ,i deleted my comment

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are only storing and return the count of maximum occurred number. Try to store number also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to achieve this.Maybe not the best.

> **Step 1:-** Sort the array in ascending order.
>
> **Step 2:** start from the end of the array and count the number of adjacent elements which are equal.

```
For example , if arr={6,3,1,3,4,3,6,5};

after sort arr={1,3,3,3,4,5,6,6};
And number of similar elements from end is 2.
```

Comment: @DeepenKshetri this is not the optimal way to perform this don't use this method.

Answer (score -1):

Brute force:

Create a Map

Now iterate over the array - for each item in the array check whether it is in the Map already (as a key).

If it is, get the value, increment it by one, and then put it back in the Map.

If it isn't in the Map already, put it in with an initial value of 1.

Comment: How is that going to help? That will give you a count of each value, but that is not the goal here.